# Несколько кнопок с одинаковой функцией js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть окно заказов за год. При нажатии на месяц открывается таблица заказов. На всех этих кнопках одинаковая функция клик. Как сделать чтобы при нажатии определенной кнопки функция срабатывала только у нее.

Comment: дайте всем уникальные id ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Не правильно задала вопрос. Кнопка нормально срабатывает, потому сто указан $(this), а вот блок который указан в функцией с таблицей заказа срабатывает у все. Как здесь сделать уточнение?

Comment: Тяжело понять в чем у Вас проблема, добавьте для наглядности пример кода

Comment: а она разве не только у нее срабатывает, когда на нее нажимают?

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно оттолкнуться от кнопки, на которую был сделан клик.
Если кнопка и таблица лежат в одном блоке, то можно дойти до общего родителя, а потом пойти в глубь до таблицы. К примеру так:

```
$(this).closest(".parent_wrap_class").find(".js-appearing-block").slideToggle('slow');
```

Если же элементы лежат в разных контейнерах, то есть много вариантов.
Можно например у кнопки в `data` атрибут положить нужное значение и при клике от него оттолкнуться.

Дайте больше информации или лучше код, тогда вероятность что вам помогут гораздо выше

Comment: Спасибо всем. Вопрос решен.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).next('.js-appearing-block').slideToggle('slow');
```

Вот что вышло. Все работает.

Comment: Возможно, это не самый лучший вариант, потому как если у вас изменится верстка и между элементами появятся еще элементы или вы их просто поменяете местами, то ваш код перестанет работать.

Comment: У вас есть другое решение?

Comment: Да, я отредактировал решение под ваши классы.

Comment: Вы могли бы поделиться своим кодом?

Comment: При использовании вашего кода у меня не срабатывает .slideToggle('slow')

Comment: Вы заменили `.parent_wrap_class ` на свой селектор?
Вот тут `$(this).closest(".parent_wrap_class").find(".js-appearing-block").slideToggle('slow');` ?
Можно проверить выборку добавив `console.log($(this).closest(".parent_wrap_class").find(".js-appearing-block"));`

Comment: выбирает кнопку по которой был сделан клик

Comment: Выложите часть решения на http://jsfiddle.net мы сможем гораздо быстрее найти решение.